# Unable to assign name to polygon

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon

I am trying to assign a name to a polygon, however visual studio keeps giving me an exception:

```
'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Isometric_Turtle_Simulator.MainWindow' that     matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line    position '9'.
```

My Code Is:

```
        for (int a = 0; a < z; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < x; b++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < y; c++)
                {
                    tile = getTile.genTile(worldData[a,b,c]);
                    tile.Name = a.ToString() + "," + b.ToString() + "," + c.ToString();
                    Canvas.SetTop(tile, posY);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(tile, posX);
                    mainCanvas.Children.Add(tile);
                    tile.MouseDown += (sender, e) => mouseDownEvent(sender, e);
                    posY = posY + 15;
                    posX = posX + 30;
                }
                posY = posY - 15 * (x - 1);
                posX = posX - 30 * (y + 1);
            }
            posX = posXOrigin;
            posY = posY - (35 + (15 * x));
            Height = Height + 35;
            mainCanvas.Height = Height;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you cannot have an illegal character in the Name property i.e. the comma. Try using an underscore instead.

Comment: I change it so it's a static string and it seems to work, but when I try and assign a variable as the name, it throws the exception.

Comment: @TimoneUK What do the variables contain, GJHix's idea is correct and works in my test. You need to make sure that there are no illegal characters in the variables that you are using to construct the name.

Comment: the variables are just integers that are part of the For loops

Comment: Feel like such a dumb ass, it's because i'm trying to give it a name starting with a number...

Comment: No problem, I can't believe I missed the number at the beginning either!